# existence of a certain type of boundedness for linear operators

Tags: operator-theory

Can someone give me an example of normed spaces $E$,$F$ and a linear operator $T: E \to F$, $T \neq 0$, with constants $c > 0, a \in \mathbb R\backslash \{1\}$ such that for all $x \in E$: $||Tx|| \le c||x||^a?$

Comment: Hmm, how about $T=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an operator does not exist for non-trivial spaces $E$ and $F$:
Suppose $Tx\neq 0$ for some $x$ so that $\lVert Tx\rVert\neq 0$. Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}>0$, then we should have $\lambda \lVert Tx\rVert \leq c \lambda^a \lVert x\rVert^a$, rewriting it to $\lambda^{1-a}\lVert Tx\rVert \leq c \lVert x\rVert^a$ we see that by taking $\lambda\rightarrow \infty$ we must have $a\geq 1$, but by taking $\lambda \rightarrow 0$ we get $a \leq 1$.